# Prolog Cut Not Working

Tags: debugging, prolog

Im having a problem with Prolog since cut is not doing what (i believe) its supposed to do:

```
% line-column handlers
checkVallEle(_, _, 6, _):- write('FAIL'), !, fail.
checkVallEle(TABULEIRO, VALUE, LINE, COLUMN):- COLUMN>5, NL is LINE+1, checkVallEle(TABULEIRO, VALUE, NL, 0).

% if this fails, it goes to the next
checkVallEle(TABULEIRO, VALUE, LINE, COLUMN):-
       (checkHorizontal(TABULEIRO, VALUE, LINE, COLUMN, 0), write('HORIZONTAL ');
        checkVertical(TABULEIRO, VALUE, LINE, COLUMN, 0), write('VERTICAL');
        checkDiagonalRight(TABULEIRO, VALUE, LINE, COLUMN, 0), write('DIAGONALRIGHT');
        checkDiagonalLeft(TABULEIRO, VALUE, LINE, COLUMN, 0), write('DIAGONALLEFT')),
        write('WIN').

% goes to the next if above fails
checkVallEle(TABULEIRO, VALUE, LINE, COLUMN):-
        NC is COLUMN+1,
        checkVallEle(TABULEIRO, VALUE, LINE, NC).
```

What I wish to do is that if the code ever reaches the first statement, that is, if the line is ever 6, it fails (since it went out of range), without checking for more possibilities. But what happens is, when it reaches the first statement, it keeps going to the below statements and ignores the cut symbol, and I dont see why. I just want the statement to fail when it reaches the first line.

I also made an experience...

```
run(6):-write('done'), !, fail.
run(X):-X1 is X+1, run(X1).
```

And this is what i get from tracing:

```
| ?- run(0).
        1      1 Call: run(0) ? 
        2      2 Call: _1079 is 0+1 ? 
        2      2 Exit: 1 is 0+1 ? 
        3      2 Call: run(1) ? 
        4      3 Call: _3009 is 1+1 ? 
        4      3 Exit: 2 is 1+1 ? 
        5      3 Call: run(2) ? 
        6      4 Call: _4939 is 2+1 ? 
        6      4 Exit: 3 is 2+1 ? 
        7      4 Call: run(3) ? 
        8      5 Call: _6869 is 3+1 ? 
        8      5 Exit: 4 is 3+1 ? 
        9      5 Call: run(4) ? 
       10      6 Call: _8799 is 4+1 ? 
       10      6 Exit: 5 is 4+1 ? 
       11      6 Call: run(5) ? 
       12      7 Call: _10729 is 5+1 ? 
       12      7 Exit: 6 is 5+1 ? 
       13      7 Call: run(6) ? 
       14      8 Call: write(done) ? 
done
       14      8 Exit: write(done) ? 
       13      7 Fail: run(6) ? 
       11      6 Fail: run(5) ? 
        9      5 Fail: run(4) ? 
        7      4 Fail: run(3) ? 
        5      3 Fail: run(2) ? 
        3      2 Fail: run(1) ? 
        1      1 Fail: run(0) ? 
no
```

What are all those Fails after the write? is it still backtracing to previous answers? Is this behaviour the reason why cut is failing in my first code? Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the last step, where you're evaluating `run(5):-run(6).`. `run(6)` fails, which means `run(5)` fails, which of course means `run(4)` fails, and so on.

As for your original problem, it's not ignoring the cut. The cut won't stop backtracking altogether, it will only stop backtracking for solutions to `checkVallEle(_,_,6,_)` - once this fails, it's going to start backtracking for more solutions with `LINE=5`.

The real problem is that the rest of your rules are under-constrained. Once it's tried the second case with `COLUMN=6`, it will try the third case with `COLUMN=6` - there's nothing there to stop it. You could get around this by throwing more cuts at it, but it's not a very nice approach.

A better approach is just to be explicit with all your constraints. There's no need for a cut in `checkVallEle(_,_,6,_)` as long as you say `LINE<6` at the start of every other rule. And if you say `COLUMN<6` in every rule (except for the second, of course), it should solve your problem with unexpected backtracking.

Comment: ah ye the recursiveness fails everything that was left behind, i get the fail train now, but i do want it to fail, and afterall this doesnt explain why my first code's cut doesnt work

Comment: @user2295607 Sorry, looks like I missed the point completely... Updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you, I understand the problem now and fixed it properly :)